# Vim Identical key bindings have slightly different behavior

Tags: vim

So I have two commands in my .vimxc that I can use to execute the current python file using python 2.whatever. The Shift-e one works fine and waits for me to hit enter to return to vim. The one using F7 does not wait for me to hit enter, but just prints to screen and goes straight back to vim, preventing me from seeing the output unless there is an error. Why do these behave differently and how would I get the F7 bind to wait for me to hit enter like the S-e bind does?

```
map <buffer> <S-e> :w<CR>:!/usr/bin/env python2 % <CR> 
map <buffer> <F7> :w<CR>:!/usr/bin/env python2 % <CR>
```

Comment: For me _both_ of these mappings return immediately without showing output...

Comment: Could you try with `nnoremap` on both, instead of `map`?

Comment: Same thing happens when I use nnoremap on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure not to have any trailing whitespace after the last `<CR>` in either case; it would cause vim to exit the output view immediately.